Launch Powershell ps1 file from RDS RemoteApp
I have a ps1 file I am trying to run from an RDS remote app. I am not sure what the -FilePath parameter should be.
New-RDRemoteApp -ConnectionBroker cb -CollectionName Applications
-Alias Testing -DisplayName "Testing"
-FilePath "C:\pw.ps1" -UserGroups "usergroup\username"
-CommandLineSetting Require -RequiredCommandLine "argument1"
-IconPath "c:\icon.ico"
I've tried
-FilePath "C:\pw.ps1"
-FilePath "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe C:\pw.ps1"
I get the error "Couldn't open this program or file. Either there was a problem with Testing or the file you're trying to open couldn't be accessed. For assistance contact your system administrator".
I am the system administrator :)
I have the ps1 file on all the host servers in the same location and it runs from the host.
If anyone has done this, please let me know the secret.
Thanks.

Please format your post properly.

New-RDRemoteApp publishes an application to a remote machine (installs). It does not launch a cmdlet.

FilePath should point to the .exe you're launching (powershell ISE in your example) and the .ps1 file (C:\pw.ps1) should be an argument (RequiredCommandLine)
